# How to get nginx with spdy on Ubuntu without having to compile it?

Tags: apt, nginx, software-installation

I observed that none of the included nginx blends has the spdy module enabled and I don't want to manually compile it for that.

I am looking for a apt repository solution but I wasn't able to find one yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently, Ubuntu has started to build nginx with spdy by default. Since Ubuntu 12.04 is an LTS release, it doesn't include these recent changes. However, there is an [Nginx  ppa](https://launchpad.net/~nginx/+archive/stable) that does includes releases of Nginx that have the spdy module enabled. You can add it by running:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable
```

Comment: You sure it builds by default? [The documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_spdy_module.html) still says otherwise.

Comment: Nginx doesn't build spdy by default, Ubuntu does in the -core, -full and -extra packages.

Comment: @btobolaski as the one who maintains nginx in main and the NGINX team PPAs, I need to correct your post, as it is wrong as it currently stands.  Spdy was only recently enabled in `nginx-extras` and `nginx-full` in Debian.  As of 14.04, with the introduction of `nginx-core` as the nginx variant in Ubuntu Main in 14.04, it also builds spdy.  The default `nginx` source code from upstream does not build spdy.  In Debian, `-full` and `-extras` build spdy.  In Ubuntu, `-core`, `-full`, and `-extras` build spdy. Nginx upstream **does not and probably will not** ever default-build spdy.

Answer (score 11):

Ubuntu's `nginx-full`, `nginx-core` and `nginx-extras` packages comes with the compiler flag `--with-http_spdy_module`. Other builds, `-light` and `-naxsi` doesn't. The below still applies if you want to compile the version from upstream.

---

Ok, first of all:

> The ngx_http_spdy_module module provides **experimental support** for SPDY. Currently, draft 3.1 of SPDY protocol is implemented.
>
> This module is **not built by default**, it should be enabled with the --with-http_spdy_module configuration parameter.

So, as you can see, is difficult that somebody will provide nginx with some characteristics that will likely not work well (I didn't). In those cases you really only solution (which is easy nonetheless) compile from sources. In an nutshell you can create your own version of nginx using:

```
apt-get source nginx
cd nginx*
editor debian/rules
```

Here you look for the line `config.status.full: config.env.full` and append along all the configure options `--with-http_spdy_module`. Save your file.

```
sudo apt-get build-dep nginx
sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev
dpkg-buildpackage
```

Done, your deb ready for installation is there. You can create a PPA that do this stuff for you too. As you can see you take more time looking for a repository than compiling it yourself.

Comment: using this as is, throws `E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list`

Comment: @TomRoggero you need to activate the `deb-src`, and such thing just go outside the scope of the question.